# GCP Cloud Build NextJS Cache

Tags: next.js, dockerfile, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I have a GCP Cloud Run application that is deployed with a Cloud Build that is triggered when a github repo. has changes pushed to main. The way these changes are made are by merging a PR.

**Cloud Build Trigger:**

- Push to a branch
- 2nd gen
- Branch = ^main$
- Cloud Build configuration file (yaml or json)

However, for some reason, the first build that happens from this trigger deploys successfully, but the changes are the same from the previous version. It isn't until I rebuild in the GCP cloud build that the new deployment has the updated code.

I am aware that NextJS uses caching by default, but not certain how that would be related to this bug given I redeploy right after the first and the code changes are present. If this weren't the case I would assume it would be an issue. This is why I assume it has something to do with my container or build process.

I checked the build logs between the build deployment and re-deployment, but they are identical with the slight exception where it is pushing to the image, and that change is that more of the hashes say they already exist like `643ccf548ae4: Layer already exists`.

**Here is my dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:18-alpine
# Set environment variables from build arguments
ARG GHOST_CONTENT_API
ARG GTM_MEASUREMENT_ID
ENV GHOST_CONTENT_API=$GHOST_CONTENT_API
ENV GTM_MEASUREMENT_ID=$GTM_MEASUREMENT_ID
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install --omit=dev --no-update-notifier
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**Here is my cloudbuild.yaml:**

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        docker build \
          --build-arg GHOST_CONTENT_API=*id* \
          --build-arg GTM_MEASUREMENT_ID=*id* \
          -t us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/${PROJECT_ID}/website-repo/my-image:latest .
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        gcloud run deploy my-website \
          --image=us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/${PROJECT_ID}/website-repo/my-image:latest \
          --platform=managed \
          --region=us-central1 \
          --allow-unauthenticated
images:
  - 'us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/${PROJECT_ID}/website-repo/my-image:latest'
```